# Templates: error when detecting whether a member function exists and my fix

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I'm using the following code from section **28.4.4** of **The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition**:

```
#pragma once
#include <type_traits>

struct substitution_failure {}; // represent a failure to declare something

template<typename T>
struct substitution_succeeded : std::true_type {};

template<>
struct substitution_succeeded<substitution_failure> : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct get_f_result
{
private:
    template<typename X>
    static auto check( X const& x ) −> decltype( f( x ) ); // can call f(x)
    static substitution_failure check( ... ); // cannot call f(x)
public:
    using type = decltype( check( std::declval<T>() ) );
};

template<typename T>
struct has_f : substitution_succeeded<typename get_f_result<T>::type> {};
```

With said code is copied and pasted into **Visual Studio Community 2015**, I get the following error:

```
\learning_cpp\c28.h(17): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
```

This points me to the line:

```
static auto check( X const& x ) −> decltype( f( x ) ); // can call f(x)
```

By looking at how **std::is_assignable** works, I came up with the following code that seems to give me the correct result (please tell me if I am doing something wrong!):

```
// similar declarations/definitions for substitution_failure &
// substitution_succeeded aside from struct names

template<typename T>
struct get_my_func_result
{
private:
    template <typename U>
    static auto check( U const& ) -> decltype( (decltype(std::declval<U>().my_func())) (std::declval<U>().my_func()), substitution_success<U>() );

    static substitution_fail check( ... );

public:
    using type = decltype( check( std::declval<T>() ) );
};

template<typename T>
struct has_my_func : substitution_success<typename get_my_func_result<T>::type> {};
```

main.cpp

```
// includes

struct A {};
struct B { void my_func(); };
struct C : public B {};

int main()
{
    has_my_func<A>::value; // false
    has_my_func<B>::value; // true
    has_my_func<C>::value; // true
    return 0;
}
```

Questions.

1. Why does the first version fail? I realize that I'm trying to detect a member function, which is why std::declval() along with other features are used in the fix, but is the book version valid too? Is it just my compiler?

**EDIT**

Answer: The line the fails has an invalid character from the copy paste operation:

```
static auto check( X const& x ) −> decltype( f( x ) ); // can call f(x)
```

Should be:

```
static auto check( X const& x ) -> decltype( f( x ) ); // can call f(x)
```

The dash character was the culprit. However, this doesn't seem to work yet, as we never specify what type to check the existence of f(x) for. I did not attempt any further fixes for that piece of code as my workaround seems to work just fine.

**END EDIT**

2. Am I doing something that isn't right 100% of the time? Could there be anything that gets past it, but that doesn't get past the book version? I'm thinking of generalizing my version.

Comment: Expression SFINAE. VS still doesn't support it.

Comment: Note that in `−>` you don't use the normal minus sign but a special char...

Comment: Once the character changed, it seems to work ([Demo](https://ideone.com/i6WSX8))

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was as simple as a special character. Thank you for pointing it out. It seems I need to pay more attention. However, the code does not seem to properly detect the function and only returns false. I don't see how that version is actually testing whether T has the member as it's simply trying to call a function without type.